# Rearraging a rotated sorted array

Tags: arrays, rotation, sorting

I have seen several questions related to *rotated sorted-arrays* e.g. for searching for the pivot element or searching for an element in such an array.

However I did not find any question related to **rearranging such an array to its original form without using sorting.**

So my question: *Is there an efficient way, or trick, to rearrange a rotated, sorted-array to original form without using extra memory?

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I would do..
I would find the starting element using a variation of binary search.

Once that is found , if you can use external memory, it can be done in O(n)
So the total time is O(lgn) + O(n) which is O(n)

Specifically to rotation:  Seeing ajay's comments, I agree that since we have to rotate in place, the best option is bubble sort. Which is O(n*m) where m is number of elements rotated.

But if we can use some storage to keep the elements on either side of the starting element, basically, if we can use external memory, it just is a question of putting each element in the right place in the new array.

Comment: how would you do it in O(n), shouldn't this be O(n.k) when n is number of total elements and k is number of rotated elements ???

Comment: If you know the starting element, then placing all subsequent elements in the right place is n steps. Correct? Havent written code but mentally thinking about it.

Comment: Are u referring to using  bubble sort  in a way to place rotated elements ?? I would really appreciate if you can provide an implementation for it.